# How can use Collections.sort() in fragment and adpater?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, collections, adapter

How can sort the distance from near to far?

I will calculate how far the user is from each point.

this is my code

```
if(seatch_bar.getText().toString().equals("")){
                    camperSiteModel.clear();
                    for(DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                        CamperSiteModel camperSiteModel1 = snapshot.getValue(CamperSiteModel.class);

                        double radLat1 = rad(camperSiteModel1.getCamperSiteLatitude());
                        double radLat2 = rad(latitude);
                        double a = radLat1 - radLat2;
                        double b = rad(camperSiteModel1.getCamperSiteLongitude()) - rad(longitude);
                        double s = 2 * Math.asin(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(Math.sin(a / 2), 2)
                                + Math.cos(radLat1) * Math.cos(radLat2)
                                * Math.pow(Math.sin(b / 2), 2)));
                        s = s * EARTH_RADIUS;
                        s = Math.round(s * 10000) / 10000;  
                        Log.i("Distance",Math.ceil(s)+"");

                        camperSiteModel1.setDistance(Math.ceil(s));
                        camperSiteModel.add(camperSiteModel1);
                        Collections.sort(camperSiteModel,new Comparator<CamperSiteModel>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(CamperSiteModel o1, CamperSiteModel o2) {
                                return o1.getCamperSiteName().compareTo(o2.getCamperSiteName());
                            }
                        });

                    }
                    camperSiteAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
```

I use this code, but it is not sort the data.

Answer (score 0):

well in case of custom classes you should provide your way of comparing them by attaching to `Collections.sort(camperSiteModel);,` a Comparator to compare between your two objects to be like this

```
 Collections.sort(camperSiteModel, new Comparator<CamperSiteModel >() {
            @Override
            public int compare(CamperSiteModel o1, CamperSiteModel o2) {
                // here you should do the comparison between data of your two objects to return an int that indicates if `o1<o2` or `o1>o2` or `o1==o2
                 return o1.getDist()-o2.getDist(); //incase of int/long
                 //return o1.getStr().equals(o2.getStr()) // incase of strings
                 //you should see how to compare between your data the right way where in case your data is a generic type like Integer/Long instead of int/long you would find the `o1.getData().equals(o2.getData())` to be very useful. 
            }
        });
```

you should try search `Comparator Java` and how to use it in google to learn more.

Comment: getDist is (lat,lng)  ?

Comment: is whatever you want, it's just an example method I wrote which would return an int/long value that you would subtract to return a value that indicates the comparison between two objects, you're free to do whatever you want inside the compare method, but you should return positive int if o1>o2, negative if o1<o2 and 0 if they're equal.